# remove selected item listbox AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, listbox

I want to remove the selected item from the listbox (liste). I import information from a xml-sheet. Then I place that information inside a listbox with a loop. How do I remove the item that has been selected from the listbox?

```
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("liste2.xml");
var xml:XML;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, ferdigLastet);
loader.load(url);
liste.selectedIndex = 0;
var antall:int=0;
function ferdigLastet(evt:Event) {
    xml = new XML(loader.data);
    antall = xml.lovbrudd.length();
    var teller:int = 0;
    while (teller<antall)
    {
        var aar:Number = xml.lovbrudd[teller].ar;  //leser fra xml-filem
        var promillekj:Number = xml.lovbrudd[teller].promille;
        var hastighet:Number = xml.lovbrudd[teller].fart;
        liste.addItem({label:aar,promille:promillekj, fart:hastighet});  //legger data i listeboksen
        //elev_array.push({navn:navnet,poeng:poenget});  // denne linjen legger dataene i et array
        teller++;
    }
}
registrer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,registrerdata);
function registrerdata(evt:MouseEvent){
    var aarregist:Number = Number(txtar.text)
    var promilleregist:Number = Number(txtpromille.text)
    var promillehastighet:Number = Number(txthastighet.text)
    liste.addItem({label:aarregist,promille:promilleregist, fart:promillehastighet});
}

fjern.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fjerndata);
function fjerndata(evt:MouseEvent){
    var fjern:int = 0;

    //want to remove selcted item from the listbox


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
liste.removeItemAt(liste.selectedIndex);
```